# How can negative numbers be represented in the Amount class?

Tags: corda

Negative numbers are not allowed in the `Amount` class according to documentation: https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.contracts/-amount/

When a `ContractState` class has an `Amount` field that can go negative (for example a balance that can be overpaid) what is the best way to represent negative numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a negative amount in Corda, because you can't pay a negative balance or hold a negative balance into an account.

however you can issue an obligation (iou), You can take a look at the r3 Corda Sample here: https://github.com/roger3cev/obligation-cordapp

Comment: Yep, `Amount` is simply a class we defined for positive amounts. You would have to define your own class that takes negative amounts if that's what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

`Amount` is designed to not allow negative amounts. It is prevented from doing so by the following `init` block:

```
init {
    // Amount represents a static balance of physical assets as managed by the distributed ledger and is not allowed
    // to become negative a rule further maintained by the Contract verify method.
    // N.B. If concepts such as an account overdraft are required this should be modelled separately via Obligations,
    // or similar second order smart contract concepts.
    require(quantity >= 0) { "Negative amounts are not allowed: $quantity" }
}
```

`AmountTransfer` is available for modelling negative transfers. Alternatively, you can simply make a copy of the `Amount` class that excludes this `init` block.